# Why does VideoWriter have a black box surrounding the video outputted?

Tags: python, opencv, video, camera

I'm using video writer to save the output of a FLIR camera. So far I've been successful and the video file saves save just fine. However, the file saved has the actual footage on top and blackness all around it. This screenshot will show what I mean:

[image]

At first I thought that I was just saving the wrong sized video but this continued to happen no matter what I set the size too. I even tried to use the `cv2.resize()` method but that also failed.

I can't seem to find anyone else that has had this problem and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
  def main(flip_v = False, alpha = 128, device = "/dev/spidev0.0"):
  # Create an array representing a 1280x720 image of
  # a cross through the center of the display. The shape of
  # the array must be of the form (height, width, color)
  a = np.zeros((240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
  lepton_buf = np.zeros((60, 80, 1), dtype=np.uint16)

  with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    # Add the overlay directly into layer 3 with transparency;
    # we can omit the size parameter of add_overlay as the
    # size is the same as the camera's resolution
    o = camera.add_overlay(np.getbuffer(a), size=(320,240), layer=3, alpha=int(alpha), crop=(0,0,80,60), vflip=flip_v)

    #Creating the VideoWriter object
    filename = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%S", time.localtime()) + ".avi"
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I', '4', '2', '0')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 8.0, (60, 80))

with Lepton(device) as l:
        last_nr = 0
        while True:
          _,nr = l.capture(lepton_buf)

          if nr == last_nr:
            # no need to redo this frame
            continue
          last_nr = nr
          cv2.normalize(lepton_buf, lepton_buf, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
          np.right_shift(lepton_buf, 8, lepton_buf)
          a[:lepton_buf.shape[0], :lepton_buf.shape[1], :] = lepton_buf

          #resize the frame before writing it to a file
          resized_frame = cv2.resize(a, (60, 80))
          out.write(np.uint8(rezised_frame))

          o.update(np.getbuffer(a))

          # Once the program has run 2000 time break the loop
          k += 1

          if k == 2000:
                 out.release()
                 break
```

Comment: Try to create Grayscale video: `out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 8.0, (60, 80), False)`. Also try `CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')`.

Comment: Can you please upload `resized_frame` as image?

Comment: @Rotem What do you mean? The image I posted was the saved value of `resized_frame`.

Comment: I mean to ask: Is the problem related to the avi video file, or is it before `out.write`? Try: cv2.imshow("resized", resized_frame) and cv2.waitKey(0). If the displayed image is larger than 60x80 pixels, the problem is `cv2.resize(a, (60, 80))` or in `a`.

Comment: I wasn't paying enough attention. I see you are converting image to RGB format, so ignore my first comment about the Grayscale video.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. When I added the `cv2.imshow` method it showed me the 80x60 image, but the window was large and it had the same blackness surrounding it. Do you think the problem is with `cv2.resize` then?

Comment: I don't know... Try to set `a` to (320,240) RGB pixels - you can set all values to 255, then use `cv2.resize(a, (60, 80))` and `cv2.imshow`, and verify if the problem is `cv2.resize` or the input to `cv2.resize` (i.e `a`)

Comment: The thing is that my program also displays the image and it appears just fine on the screen. Although it's stretched out, there is no black space. Only when I use cv2.imshow do I get that black space. Does that give you any idea as to what could be wrong with it? Also how would I change `a` to RGB? I'm using code provided by the manufacturer and didn't know that it was doing any conversion TBH.

Comment: What's this? o = camera.add_overlay(np.getbuffer(a), size=(320,240), layer=3, alpha=int(alpha), crop=(0,0,80,60), vflip=flip_v)

Comment: @Micka The way this program works is by taking the display of the FLIR thermal camera and layering it over the display of a Raspberry Pi camera. That's part is adding the overlay.

Comment: so maybe that overlay produces the border?!?

Comment: So the Raspberry Pi has a much higher resolution then the FLIR. It makes sense that the output made by the FLIR would be smaller. However, when the image renders on my screen and I see the video the display of the FLIR is expanded out to match the resolution of the Pi Cam. I just don't understand why the video output doesn't do the same.

Comment: sorry I don't have a crystal ball to find out what kind of displaying routines you've got and what happens anywhere.